# Meu vídeo não roda no background css em tablets ou ipads. Apenas em PC

Tags: css, html5

Olá pessoal tenho um vídeo que roda normalmente em background css no PC. Mas quando acesso o site por tablets ou ipads ele não roda.

**Veja o código:**

```
<video autoplay loop poster="torre.jpg" class="bg_video">
            <source src="bg.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg_video{
            position: fixed; 
            right: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 100%; 
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto; 
            height: auto; 
            z-index: -1000;
            background: url(torre.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size: cover; 
        }
```

Já coloquei ele no formato conforme pedem MP4 e WEBM, mas nada resolve.

Comment: Já verificou se o navegador aceita tal recurso?

Comment: @Mike é o mesmo do pc

Comment: Mas ele já rodou em outros navegadores no teu PC?

Comment: @Mike sim, normalmente. Só não roda em dispositivos móveis.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com rodar em background?

Comment: @Pablo Rodar em background eu consegui. Só que ele só está rodando em PC. Em tablets e ipads ele não roda.

Comment: Não estou entendendo o que você quer dizer com rodar em background. Você quer dizer rodar enquanto o navegador está minimizado?

Comment: @Pablo Quando digo rodar quer dizer que o vídeo não executa em tablets ou ipads. Apenas em PC

Answer (score 1):

Em uma situação similar eu consegui com que o vídeo fosse exibido tanto em dispositivos iOS mobile quanto em desktops com duas ações:

1 - Privilegiando a versão .mp4 (colocando-a em primeiro lugar)

```
<video autoplay loop poster="torre.jpg" class="bg_video">
    <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="bg.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

2 - Fazendo com que os vídeos fossem renderizados com o parâmetro `Field Order: None (progressive)`. Você precisará realizar o re-encoding dos vídeos, caso o Field Order seja diferente.

O suporte a Codecs ainda não é padronizado em todos os browsers.

Comment: Como faço esta implementação?

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini Eu alterei a resposta para torná-la mais clara.